# Make my userscript wait for other scripts to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

[**Edit:** I'm replacing the original, confusing question with a simplified example demonstrating the problem.]

**Background**

I'm trying to write a userscript which will run in Chrome. This script needs to call a JavaScript function `AlertMe()` that is outside of the userscript -- this function is part of the page and contains variables that are generated dynamically on the server-side, so it isn't possible to re-write this function in my userscript.

**Code**

Script on the page ([visit the page](http://martinsmucker.com/demo/alertme.html)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AlertMe()
    {
        alert("Function AlertMe was called!");
        // then do stuff with strings that were dynamically generated
        // on the server so that I can't easily rewrite this into the userscript
    }
</script>
```

My userscript ([install it in Chrome](http://martinsmucker.com/demo/martinsmucker.user.js)):

```
function tryAlert()
{
    if (typeof AlertMe == "undefined") {
        console.log('AlertMe is undefined.');
        window.setTimeout(tryAlert, 100);
    }
    else {
        AlertMe();
    }
}

tryAlert();
```

**The Problem**

When I tried to simply call the function, Chrome's console let me know that `AlertMe is not defined`. Thinking that this was because my userscript was running before all other scripts had been loaded, I used `setTimeout` to wait for the `AlertMe` function to become defined.

Unfortunately, if you install the script then visit the page, you'll see that this just outputs `AlertMe is undefined.` forever and never calls the function.  If you type `typeof AlertMe` into Chrome's console, it will correctly respond with `"function"`, so why is it that my userscript always thinks that `AlertMe` is undefined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a matter of timing.

You're bumping into Greasemonkey's security restrictions, which prevent you from executing functions in the page. Please see my answer to this previous question for an explanation and some safe workarounds:

[UserScripts & Greasemonkey: calling a website's JavaScript functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006460/userscripts-greasemonkey-calling-a-websites-javascript-functions)

Comment: Thanks so much.  Since I was just calling one function, I used the location hack and it worked perfectly.  Plus, that was a good read, and might be a very useful resource in the future.

Answer (score 9):

You can always write a little function that checks to see if the function is loaded

```
function waitForFnc(){
  if(typeof absearch == "undefined"){
    window.setTimeout(waitForFnc,50);
  }
  else{
    runMyFunction();
  }
}

function runMyFunction(){
    var urlParams = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&'),
        username = "",
        hscEmailInput = document.getElementById('userfield6'),
        i = 0;
    if (urlParams !== "") {
        for (i = 0; i < urlParams.length; i++) {
            if (urlParams[i].substr(0,4) === "USER") {
                username = urlParams[i].replace('USER=', '');
                hscEmailInput.value = username + '@example.com';
                absearch('&PAGESIZE=1');
            }
        }
    }
}

waitForFnc();
```

Comment: I like the timeout option, but wasn't sure on the specifics. Thanks for the example... I'll give this a shot.

Comment: See my update to the question.  My script eternally thinks that `absearch` is undefined, even though I can ask the console for `typeof absearch` and it correctly tells me that it's a function.  Ideas?

Comment: Okay, I completely rewrote the question. There is now a simplified test case and userscript that you can install if you want to test the issue yourself. Even after Chrome knows that the function is defined, my userscript still thinks it's undefined.  I have no idea why.

Comment: @Michael Martin-Smucker - It's a matter of security, not timing. Please see my answer.

Comment: @lwburk, thanks. @epascarello, +1 because you answered my question as it was originally phrased, and as a bonus I got to learn about `window.setTimeout` in the process.  Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is indeed that your script runs too early, perhaps checking and waiting until the DOM is ready is the solution: [Relying on DOM readiness to invoke a function (instead of window.onload)](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml)

**Edit**

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready) might also prove to be useful.

Comment: The DOM ready event means just that: the document has been loaded. This event happens before external resources (like scripts) have been loaded. If you need something to happen after all resources are available, you should use the window.onload event instead.

Comment: @ithcy I don't think that's true. While I can't find any definitive answer- [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events) and [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=481534) seem to suggest that images and CSS are considered external resources- JavaScript is parsed as it appears. I tested this in FF4b11 by modifying and hosting [this page](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html) locally and accessing it through a proxy throttled to 33kbps. The DOMContentLoaded event fired only once the external JS I added was loaded.

Comment: My belief system - you've destroyed it! :)

Comment: @ithcy If it helps, I learned something today- I only thought about this when you pointed it out :)