# Simple user script isn't working anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code

```
//
// ==UserScript==
// @name           test
// @description    test
// @version        0.2
// @namespace      test
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==
$(function(){
    alert('d');
});
```

and when I'm trying to execut it in my chrome, it installs as an extension, but executes nowhere (stackoverflow has jQuery already so I think I don't need to include that again. )

What's wrong?

Comment: Stack overflow uses `jQuery.noConflict()` so you'll need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`, but @Brock_Adams is right, you need to inject..

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006460/userscripts-greasemonkey-calling-a-websites-javascript-functions/5006952#5006952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome userscript JS and the page's JS cannot interact with each other.  You'll need to inject your JS into the page...

```
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL)
{
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";

    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

    var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || d.body || d.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node ("alert('d');");
```

Comment: It works with simple (function(){

    alert('D');
});   thank you though

Comment: Yes, but that function is pure JS in the script scope.  You cannot use jQuery that way.

Comment: well, now it stopped to work with my first comment. What the hell? Thank you for your tip, I'll try it later :)

Comment: could we move to chat please?

Comment: Okay, [here's a chatroom for this question](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1712/simple-user-script-isnt-working-anywhere).