# Monitor a tag for style changes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I want my userscript to monitor this tag for changes:

```
<div id="moni" style="text-align: center; width: 773px; display: none; ">Offline</div>
```

The changes are to the style. `display:none;` sometimes changes to `display:block;`.

How do I monitor this through javascript?

Comment: If you have access to the code that modifies the style then you can use jquery to trigger a custom event whenever the style is updated. Otherwise you have to periodically check the style.

Comment: Does your page use jQuery or any other javascript framework? If so, please update tags.

Comment: I've actually found that this monitors a id. document.getElementById('search').addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", ButtonClick, false);
function ButtonClick (zEvent){
  alert('its changed');
}

Comment: Doing that is not a good idea.  [Mutation events are buggy and slow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events), and [they are deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents).  They'll disappear in future browser versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your ***real goal*** to just keep that div from displaying?
If so, then just use CSS in your script, like so:

```
GM_addStyle ('#moni {display: none !important;}');
```

---

But, if you really want to monitor for changes, here are some choices:

1. Poll for changes.  This is the simplest, most robust method.
   For example (**No jQuery required**):

   ```
   function checkForMoniDisplayChange () {
       this.lastDisp   = this.lastDisp  ||  "";
       var moniDiv     = document.getElementById ("moni")
       var moniDisp    = window.getComputedStyle (moniDiv).getPropertyValue ("display");

       if (moniDisp != this.lastDisp) {
           // DO SOMETHING
           //console.log (moniDisp);
       }
       this.lastDisp   = moniDisp;
   }

   //--- 150 is a good compromise between UI response and browser load.
   window.setInterval (checkForMoniDisplayChange, 150);
   ```
2. Hook into the target-page's javascript that is making the change (if any).
   For example, if the target page uses the javascript function `display (elem)` to show that node, then you can *often* [**inject**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5006952/331508) code similar to:

   ```
   var _old_display    = display;
   var display         = function (elem) {
       // DO SOMETHING
       _old_display (elem);    // Optional, depending on your goals.
       // DO SOMETHING MORE
   };
   ```
3. Use the brand-new [`MutationObserver`s](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) to monitor the element for changes to its class and/or style attributes.
   If you are going to do this, it's best to do it via [Google's *Mutation Summary* library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/).  Ask a new question for more information on this approach.

---

Note that for security reasons, javascript cannot detect every style change.  For example, your script won't be able to get the color of visited links.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible).  They will show you how to mod jQuery itself to get what you want.

If you want to just poll, you could use this:

```
function foo(){
    $('#moni').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            //do something
        }
    });
} //foo()
window.setInterval(foo, 100);
```

Modify the `100` to be a reasonable number of milliseconds for your situation.