# Trigger field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fill a website with the help of a greasemonkey script.
This website has some required fields and I can't submit the form when they are not filled in.

Now, I have the following problem:
I fill the required fields using jQuery's `.val`. When I now click the submit button - even manually with the mouse - then it says that some of the required fields are not filled in.
When I click in one of the affected fields with the mouse and then click the submit button again, it accepts the value and proceeds.

My question is:
How do I figure out which event the website listens to? Or:
How can I trigger the validation of the fields from my script?

Update: I tried the following command directly in Chrome's developer tools' console:

```
jQuery('#ext-comp-1080').click().focus().focusin()
                        .val('my value').change().blur().focusout()
```

Comment: Maybe see what function handles validation and call it directly from the userscript?

Comment: trigger `.change()` event on those fields after `.click()`

Comment: Maybe dis can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Comment: I did some research and posted a followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443597/trigger-synthetic-extjs-event-from-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, the validation is tied to a `blur` event.

In jQuery, you would use:

```
$('#thingToBlur').blur();
```

That said -- I have never triggered events through a UserScript, so I'm not sure if they will correctly hit the element in `unsafeWindow`.

If you need to force-ably run JavaScript on the page (and that includes firing the events there), see this question:

[UserScripts & Greasemonkey: calling a website's JavaScript functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006460/userscripts-greasemonkey-calling-a-websites-javascript-functions)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. For simplicity's sake, I just open the page and start Chrome's developer tools for testing and enter my code directly in the console. Like this, I believe the problem mentioned in your link should not apply - am I correct? Anyway, because I tried these "obvious" events already, I asked if there is a way to figure out, what does trigger the validation on that particular website.

Comment: If the common things don't trigger it, the only other real option is to read the source ...

Comment: I updated my question with the code I am using. Maybe you see something obvious. Reading the code - I tried to do that, but there are no event handlers, they seem to get attached dynamically. I even tried to figure out the attached handlers at runtime, but no luck here either. Any idea where else to look? Or, is there a technique that allows me to log any change to the internal state (HTML or Javascript) of a website?

Answer (score 0):

Since after you change the file by using `.val()` and then you click into a field and click submit it most likely listens on `change` or `blur` event.

```
// set value
$(selector).val(value);

// trigger click
$(selector).click();

// trigger change or blur
$(selector).change();
```

You could also do method chaining if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but as per my comment to Jeremy's answer, this doesn't work on that particular website.