# Trigger synthetic ExtJS event from jQuery or vanilla javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, extjs, extjs3

There exists a website implemented with ExtJS 3.1.
I want to pre-fill some fields automatically. The problem is, that some fields are not validated by ExtJS when automatically filling them.
I can trigger the validation by firing ExtJS's blur event:

```
field.fireEvent('blur', field);
```

However, I don't want to do this. I want that validation to be triggered by a normal event triggered via jQuery:

```
$field.blur();
```

**What I am asking here is the following:**
How to trigger the blur event of a textbox in the same way the browser does it, so that also ExtJS's event handlers run?

BTW: The reason why I don't want to manually fire the ExtJS event is simple: This solution seems to work for ExtJA 3.1 but no longer for 4.2 and I don't want to write special handling code for every version of ExtJS.

---

If you want to play around a little bit:
Here is the URL: https://www.pantaenius.com/en/service/login/request-a-quote.html?utm_source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pantaenius.com%2Fen%2Famerican-yacht-insurance.html&utm_medium=direct&domain_segment=33
Open it in Chrome, open Chrome's developer console and paste the following text:

```
delete console.log

var $city = jQuery('#ext-comp-1080');
var city = Ext.ComponentMgr.all.filterBy(function(x) { return x.isXType('combo') && x.id==='ext-comp-1080'; }).items[0];

var blurEventFireFn = city.events.blur.listeners[0].fireFn;

city.events.blur.listeners[0].fireFn = function(field) { console.log('ExtJS blur fired!'); blurEventFireFn(field); };
```

When you click in the City field and then in some other field, you will see the output `ExtJS blur fired!` in the console. You will see the same output when you execute `city.fireEvent('blur', city);`. However, you won't see that output when you execute `$city.blur();`, `$city.trigger('blur');` or

```
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('blur', true, true);
$city.get(0).dispatchEvent(event);
```

Any ideas how to create this bridge between normal events and ExtJS events would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the native event with your bit of code does work (in non-IE browsers):

```
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('blur', true, true);
$city.get(0).dispatchEvent(event);
```

However you should avoid the problem rather than giving it a weird cure, by using the [`validator`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField-cfg-validator) of the field instead of a blur event listener. This way, the `setValue` method of the field will trigger its validation...

If you're really stuck with it, instead of adding a (probably fragile) layer of complexity by simulating events, I would just call the [`onBlur`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-method-onBlur) method of the fields directly. That's the handler that is added to the DOM by Ext. It is present in 3.x and 4.x, and it doesn't rely on specific browsers...

Comment: I know that my code works to simulate the native event. Problem is that it doesn't trigger the ExtJS event. I also can't change that website's code, I am trying to create a userscript that simplifies some tasks. Calling validate on the field doesn't produce the desired result either. Try to add a value using jQuery, call `validate` on the field and then click on the "Forward" button. It still says that the City field needs to filled out. Code `$city.val('some value'); city.validate()`