# How to call page Javascript function, from a user script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How can I call a Javascript function, defined in a script in the HTML page, from a user script?

I have a user script in Chromium loaded by dragging my.user.js to the `chrome://extensions/` page. The script which Chromium sees as an extension is similar to this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://192.168.0.1/common_page/login.html
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById('loginPassword').value="a-password"
LoginFunc()
```

The script can do things like `console.log('hello')` fine. I am trying to call a function called `LoginFunc` defined on line 644 in the [page HTML](https://pastebin.com/gEzqXEKZ).

I can call `LoginFunc` with the Javascript console in developer tools and it does exactly what I want. Every way I have tried to call `LoginFunc` from my user script just gives `LoginFunc is not defined` though.

I have tried:

```
setTimeout(LoginFunc(),10000)
```

---

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if (typeof LoginFunc === "function") {  
    LoginFunc()
  }
},10000)
```

---

```
setInterval(function(){
  if (typeof LoginFunc === "function") {  
    LoginFunc()
  }
},1000)
```

---

```
window.onload = LoginFunc
```

---

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', LoginFunc, false);
```

Comment: In what scope is LoginFunc declared?

Comment: are you calling `LoginFunc` in a *content script* that is injected into the page?

Comment: @JayGould I'm not sure. Is it global scope? I linked to the page HTML in the question now.

Comment: [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006460/userscripts-greasemonkey-calling-a-websites-javascript-functions)

Comment: a little more info about the extension would help, i.e. where in your extension are you trying to call `LoginFunc`

Comment: For Chrome Extensions, I believe [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) is as close as you can get.

Comment: I got it to work with `location.assign("javascript:LoginFunc();void(0)")` from that @James. Thank you. Not sure if this is the best way to do it. If this is not best practice, please tell us what is. Thanks very much all

Comment: Simply [create a script element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script) with the code you want to run in the page context.

Comment: @wOxxOm script injection was mentioned in James' reference. Unless there's something wrong with using location, I think I'll use it for a simple, single call like this. It's certainly shorter. Thanks though

Comment: Well, apart from being an ancient hack, there's probably nothing wrong, if it works.